# injecting terraform variables in a bash script

Tags: bash, terraform

I have a bash script which has got lot of variables in it with `$` sign, a sample is as below

```
if [ -z "${edition}" ]; then
  edition=newed
fi
```

i have some terraform variables which needs to go into this bash script, i use the below code

```
 data "template_file" "newdata" {
   template = file("data.sh")
   vars = {
     useid = var.useid
     usekey = var.usekey
   }
}
```

and in `user_data` i use this

```
data.template_file.newdata.rendered
```

Here, the terraform also tries to see the bash variables as terraform variables and says this

```
Unknown variable; There is no variable named "edition".
```

How can i make this work, what exactly am i missing here.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `$` in the Terraform?  Like so: `\$`?

Comment: @TrippKinetics where? in which file?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The template_file data source renders *all* variables in the file, even those not corresponding to any vars. This design decision (poor in my opinion) was discussed [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2104) a long time ago, but as far as I can tell nothing has changed since then.

So to get things working, change your script to:

```bash
if [ -z "$${edition}" ]; then
  edition=newed
fi
```

Note the usage of the `$$`.

Answer (score -1):

It depends a bit on how the Terraform configuration is accessing the shell script. It *looks like* what Terraform is doing is to read the file and embedding the content of the shell script file into its own configuration.  So, you have to escape the variables in the script.

Rather than:

```
${edition}
```

You'd use:

```
\${edition}
```

That way Terraform will ignore it as a variable.

Comment: Did you test this?